# Java JPanel Layout - New Line after specific Width

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I have an application where the user can define tags meant for files in a directory. A directory can be assigned tags through JCheckBox isntances, one for each tag, which I will keep in a JPanel. 
This means that the number of JCheckBoxes will depend on how many tags the user creates, and the width of each JCheckBox will depend on the length of the name for the individual tags.

What I want to be able to do is be able to tell the JPanel holding these JCheckBoxes *to always have a width of XXX pixels* (essentially, setting its dimensions). I then want it to be able to understand when a new tag is added which would have made the width exceed the limit, and react by putting that JCheckBox on a new Row.

If you happend to know how to force the text of JCheckBoxes to not exceed a certain width by making it take up two lines of text, that is fine too since then I can just use GridLayout for the JPanel.

Comment: Place the checkboxes in a JPanel with a **FlowLayout** which will handle wrapping.

Comment: @JoopEggen Kinda funny, I came here after having read that FlowLayout didn't work that way, but it seems like it does (if you set the preferred size of the Panel)

Comment: Yes the preferred size is crucial almost everywhere in swing layouting.